# Infinite loop in Spring boot AuthenticationFilter

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, spring-boot, jwt

We have recently converted Java configured spring application to spring boot and the old application was working fine but however after converting it into spring boot project we are having serious problems in endpoints that were secured by JWT tokens all of them are creating an endless loop and finally throwing  `StackOverflow` Exceptions.

Below is the very abstract example of the whole JWT token filer without actual code because the original code is very lengthy and I feel this is enough for someone who is good at spring to understand.

```
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {



  public TokenAuthenticationFilter() {
    setAuthenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {
        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            return null; // no different in the original code 
        }
    });
    setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        @Override
        protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            String context = request.getContextPath();
            String fullURL = request.getRequestURI();
            String url = fullURL.substring(fullURL.indexOf(context) + context.length());
            return url;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
            String url = determineTargetUrl(request, response);
            request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
        }
    });
    setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new RequestMatcher() {
        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return getTokenRequest(request);
        }
    });
}


private boolean getTokenRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String userAuthToken = request.getHeader("X-Auth-Token");
    return userAuthToken != null;
}


@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

    List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(1);
    roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER_ROLE"));
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("imaa95@gmail.com", "", roles);
    return authRequest;
 }
}
```

Basically in the actual code token is validated within the `attemptAuthentication` method once that is done spring calls the `onAuthenticationSuccess` method, inside of that based on a logic we are forwarding the requests to the controller

`request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);`

I think this is the reason for the infinite loop because this creates a new request that will again be captured by the same filter, but the strange thing is that this exact code worked without any issue in the previous java based configuration so we would really happy if someone can spot the issue and provide us a way to fix it with minimum code changes

As requested here is the security config

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider())
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/allData").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .formLogin().usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(getLoginSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                                        AuthenticationException e) throws IOException,
                            ServletException {
                        response.getWriter().write("Login Failed :(");
                    }
                })
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher( new AntPathRequestMatcher( "/logout" ) )
                    .logoutSuccessHandler( getLogoutSuccessHandler() )
                    .deleteCookies( "uc" )
                    .invalidateHttpSession( true )
                    .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(getEntryPoint());

    http.addFilterBefore(new TokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that request is getting stuck in endless loop as login page is also getting authenticated. In your config,try putting permitAll() immediately after loginPage.

```
.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
```

followed by other configuration.

**EDIT:**
Since the above fix did not work, I suspect that authentication is getting stuck between 2 authentication providers might be causing the issue. Can you try injecting the daoAuthprovider in the Token filter. Way to do it is:
Remove the config:

```
authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider())
```

from

```
http.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider())
            .authorizeRequests()
```

And modify the following config:

```
http.addFilterBefore(new TokenAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

The daoauthProvider can be configured like:

```
@Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthProvider);
        }
```

And in your `TokenAuthenticationFilter`, you can do this:

```
public TokenAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {       
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }
```

I am suggesting the solution based on my past experience with the problem. I am not sure whether it will apply to your case or not.

Comment: Sorry man does not work,  can we do this ??

 @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
            String url = determineTargetUrl(request, response);
            request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
        }

shouldn't this create another filter call ?

Comment: I think now we should resort to debugger. Putting break points on both authentication providers will tell the exact cause of endless loop.